# Flutter Appbar title not center when push to the page and when action button is available

Tags: flutter, center, appbar

I added appbar to my scaffold on my flutter page. Everything works perfectly expect the asset SVG image used for the title not always center. When I push from another to the page of my appbar the title with the SVG image moves to the right and if the page is visited directly it moves to the left. I tried using padding for this but still the same. The question is how can I make the title stick to the center and not affect by action button image on the left and right. Below is my code:

```js
return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(40.0), // here the desired height
        child: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: colorGreen,
          title:Center(child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Center(
                //padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 36.0),
                child: Center(
                  child: SvgPicture.asset(assetName,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      width: 20,
                      height: 20,
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      semanticsLabel: 'Hobber'),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          )),
          actions: <Widget>[
            GestureDetector(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 12.0),
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.notifications,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
              onTap: () {},
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    body:Container(child:Text("My body message"),)

);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
  appBar: AppBar(
    centerTitle: true,
  ......
```

Removing unnecessary widgets would get this result to your appBar:

```
    appBar: PreferredSize(
      preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(40.0), // here the desired height
      child: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: colorGreen,
        title: SvgPicture.asset(assetName,
            color: Colors.white,
            width: 20,
            height: 20,
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
            semanticsLabel: 'Hobber'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          GestureDetector(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 12.0),
              child: Icon(
                Icons.notifications,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
            onTap: () {},
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
```

Comment: You're using a Center inside a Center, that's inside a Column with only one Widget, that is inside another Center widget. I'll edit my answer and post a cleaner code for you.